# NSOutlineView gradient background

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'm trying to implement a NSOutlineView subclass with gradient background:

```
- (void)drawBackgroundInClipRect:(NSRect)clipRect {
    [gradient drawInRect:clipRect angle:90];
}
```

It almost works as supposed to:

[image]

But when I resize the view, gradient "breaks":

[image]
[image]

Gradient is being rendered properly everywhere, except under the area that is covered by items. When I change key state of the window (by switching to another app) that area gets rendered correctly too, as will as if I collapse the Queues item. What am I missing? What should I do to update background in that area after resize?

Comment: I can see that color scheme getting hard to read, especially when you get toward 15+ queues.

Comment: Yes, I know, but at this point I'm just trying to figure out how to make a gradient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to migrate to view-based NSOutlineView, the following code works perfectly with it:

```
- (void)drawBackgroundInClipRect:(NSRect)clipRect {
    [gradient drawInRect:self.frame angle:90];
}
```

Comment: `self.frame`? Shouldn't that be `self.bounds`?

Answer (score 2):

The clip rectangle is the area that has changed, not necessarily the entire area of the gradient. If you want the gradient to start at the top of the (visible area of the) view, and end at the bottom of the (visible area of the) view, then you need to draw the gradient with the same rectangle every time.

Use [the `NSRectClip` function](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Miscellaneous/AppKit_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSRectClip) to clip to the given rectangle, which will limit your drawing as you're supposed to, then ask yourself (the outline view) for [your enclosing scroll view](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/enclosingScrollView), ask the scroll view for [the visible rect](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSScrollView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSScrollView/documentVisibleRect), and tell the scroll view to [convert that rect to the outline view's coordinate system](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/convertRect%3atoView%3a).

Comment: This is what I ended up with: `NSRect visibleRect = self.enclosingScrollView.visibleRect; NSRect rect = [self.enclosingScrollView convertRect:visibleRect toView:self]; 
[gradient drawInRect:rect angle:90];`

Unfortunately, it behaves exactly the same. I tried adding logging of rect's origin and size, when I change key state of the window it logs exactly the same rect, as when I was resizing it, but resizing "breaks" gradient and switching to another window "fixes" it. I don't understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I think the outline view doesn't redraw existing items when the size changes, because normally it doesn't need to. In your view, add a notification listener for `NSViewFrameDidChangeNotification`, and call `-setNeedsDisplay` on the view when the frame changes.

Comment: Tried this, doesn't work. I called -setNeedsDisplay in -setFrameSize instead of listening for NSViewFrameDidChangeNotification, but I don't think that makes any difference.

Comment: Did you check that -setFrameSize was actually called?

Comment: Yes, I did. It is being called as expected.